# Authenticate wink hub with php client using oauth2

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authenticate my wink hub with oauth2 using my php client. I am not sure how to register my app with wink and where to define redirect url and key.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: "Wink wink nudge nudge";  "say no more, say no more"

Comment: Mike, I am using /oauth2/token request(http://docs.wink.apiary.io/) and i am able to get access and refresh token but i am struggling how to navigate on wink login screen(authenticate from wink) using my app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact support@winkapp.com and ask them to generate you an id/secret pair.  The wait time is currently 2-4 weeks (I wonder why it takes them so long)

Comment: not correct, took me just a couple of days to receive my confirmation. Fill everything on the web, no calls.